# Alert Dialog negative button to same activity

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am trying a simple app, where user enters his number. And I show an alert dialog to confirm his mobile number. If user chooses "YES" I am redirecting him to next activity. But the problem is, if user select "NO" I want to show the same activity for editing the number.

Now I am doing this by calling an Intent of the same activity. But it is a bad practice. How can I show the same activity with last entered number in the activity?

Here is how I tried.
on button press

```
phoneNum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPhoneNumber);
String phNum = phoneNum.getText().toString();
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
        MainActivity.this);
alertDialog.setTitle("CONFIRM");
alertDialog.setMessage("Is this your correct number? \n" + phNum
        + " a SMS will be sent to verify your phone number.");
alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                sendOtp();
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        Activity2Activity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                // dialogInterface.cancel();
                Intent sameIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(sameIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });
alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: alertDialog.dismiss();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you just need to display the same activity, just dismiss the dialog box while you click the negative button.

```
alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override 
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        alertDialog.dismiss();   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can read this reference document: 
[Official Doc : Dialog Dismiss](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#DismissingADialog)
Notice this sentence: 
**When the user touches any of the action buttons created with an AlertDialog.Builder, the system dismisses the dialog for you.**
No matter the user click which button that generated by Builder, the system dismisses the dialog.

```
alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        //Just leave it empty here.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
getDialog().dismiss();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this. it Will Help You

```
phoneNum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    String phNum = phoneNum.getText().toString();
    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            MainActivity.this);
    alertDialog.setTitle("CONFIRM");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Is this your correct number? \n" + phNum
            + " a SMS will be sent to verify your phone number.");
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)        {
                     sendOtp();
                     Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                     Activity2Activity.class);
                     startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            });
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    // dialogInterface.cancel();

                }
            });
    alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want anything to happen, you don't have to use the `OnClickListener` you can just put a `null`.

For eg:

```
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void SureEvent() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    ad.setMessage("Are You sure Want to exit ?");

    ad.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Closing..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();//Syntax:DialogInterface_varible.method()
                    //dialog.cancel();
                }
            })
            .show();
}
```